# Where to put a massive string in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

The point of RSpec is to hide implementation details and provide a clean test suite and spec. I've created a stub for an HTTP request that returns a fairly large (100 or so lines) JSON response. This is only used for one or two tests. Putting this string inside of a context, before block, etc., seems like it would completely eradicate the cleanness of the testing spec. Declaring it at the top of the spec would be annoying for people trying to read the file. Yet, just being a simple string, it doesn't seem to warrant a helper module. Thoughts?

Comment: Agreed, put it in spec/fixtures/your_cool_file.json and load it as needed

Comment: is there no rspec extension that handles this? like file fixtures or whatever?